# How to reverse a string using recursion?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, recursion

I'm trying out a simple program which would allow me to print out the reverse word of "computer". When I run my code, I received a runtime error  *RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp* .

May I know what had happen and how can I solve it?

```
def reverse(str1):
    if str1 == '':
        return str1
    else:
        return reverse(str1[1:] + str1[0])

print reverse('retupmoc')
```

Comment: Other than a programming exercise, I assume you are aware of this way of reversing a string: `'retupmoc'[::-1]`

Comment: You can also reduce the code to `return reverse(str1[1:]) +  str1[0] if str1 else ""`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
return reverse(str1[1:] + str1[0])
```

You are concatenating the rest of the string with the first character and passing to the `reverse` function. So, the length of the string never reduces.

It should have been

```
return reverse(str1[1:]) + str1[0]
```

Now, you are passing only the rest of the string, excluding the first character to the recursive `reverse` function. So, on each recursive level, one character will be removed from the string and it will eventually meet your base condition.

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can reverse strings in one simple line, and avoid recursive entirely, unless it is some assignment with a requirement.

So do: `s[::-1]`, where `s` is the variable name of the string to be reversed.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer itself.